# Narrow down a type of an object property within filter & map chain in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to narrow and type guard a property of an specific object while filtering and mapping but I'm not fully understanding how to do it.

Let's say I got the following array of Objects of interface Person:

```
interface IPerson {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   height: number | null;
}

const personArray: IPerson[] = [...]
```

Let's say I would like to filter those that aren't null first and then map the result and do something with those filtered out.

```
personArray
   .filter((person) => person.height !== null)
   .map((person) => this.doSomethingAboutIt(person.height))
```

The `doSomethingAboutIt` function expects a number only, not a null. That's why I wanted to filter non-null first. But TypeScripts shows an error saying that doSomethingAboutIt is expecting a `number`, and not a `number | null`. Even thought there shouldn't be any null during the map function. Of course TypeScript doesn't know this yet. I thought it would be automatically inferred but I was wrong.

How can I narrow down the type to only number on object properties?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need a type guard on the filter callback.

Comment: Yea, but i just don't know how to accomplish it in this example. I know you can do stuff like `filter((item): item is Type => item !== null))`. But don't know how to do it with object properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use type guard as follows:

```
interface IPerson {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    height: number | null;
}

const doSomethingAboutIt = (h: number) => {};

const personArray: IPerson[] = [];
personArray
    .filter((person): person is IPerson & { height: number } => person.height !== null)
    .map((person) => doSomethingAboutIt(person.height));
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Thanks. Didn't occur to me the concatenation `&` there to specify object property typings.